Nginx Layer-4 loadbalancer for 6 node k8s cluster
I'm trying to create a nginx Layer-4 loadbalancer for my kubernetes cluster, which is a RKE2 with 6 nodes:
Control-Plane-1 => IP: 192.168.100.11 , OS: Ubuntu 22.04 , Hostname: kuber-master-1
Control-Plane-2 => IP: 192.168.100.12 , OS: Ubuntu 22.04 , Hostname: kuber-master-2
Control-Plane-3 => IP: 192.168.100.13 , OS: Ubuntu 22.04 , Hostname: kuber-master-3

Worker-1 => IP: 192.168.100.14 , OS: Ubuntu 22.04 , Hostname: kuber-worker-1
Worker-2 => IP: 192.168.100.15 , OS: Ubuntu 22.04 , Hostname: kuber-worker-2
Worker-3 => IP: 192.168.100.16 , OS: Ubuntu 22.04 , Hostname: kuber-worker-3

L4 Load Balancer => ip: 192.168.100.100

This is my attempt for the load balancer, but I do not understand which upstream / server parts I really have to add and which IPs belongs where. Where should I place the control node IPs and where the worker node IPs?
I guess I've totally messed up everything.
nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

stream {
    upstream http {
        server 192.168.100.14:80;
        server 192.168.100.15:80;
        server 192.168.100.16:80;
    }
    upstream ssl {
        server 192.168.100.14:443;
        server 192.168.100.15:443;
        server 192.168.100.16:443;
    }
    upstream rancher_nodes {
        server 192.168.100.11:9345 fail_timeout=1s max_fails=2;
        server 192.168.100.12:9345 fail_timeout=1s max_fails=2;
        server 192.168.100.13:9345 fail_timeout=1s max_fails=2;
    }
    upstream kubernetes_nodes {
        server 192.168.100.11:6443 fail_timeout=1s max_fails=2;
        server 192.168.100.12:6443 fail_timeout=1s max_fails=2;
        server 192.168.100.13:6443 fail_timeout=1s max_fails=2;
    }


    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass http;
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass ssl;
    }
    server {
        listen 9345;
        proxy_pass rancher_nodes;
    }
    server {
        listen 6443;
        proxy_pass kubernetes_nodes;
    }
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


As per this DEV blog by Arman Shafiei
In a layer-4 load balancer, you typically don’t target control plane nodes. These nodes manage the internal state of the cluster.
Your upstream sections for rancher _ nodes and kubernetes_nodes are currently targeting the control plane IPs.
The upstream section for http now points to your worker node IPs on port 80, assuming your application pods are deployed there. You can optimally add a health checks directive to monitor the health of your backend servers.
The remaining server blocks for ports 443, 9345 and 6443 probably for HTTPS,Rancher and kubernetes API are okay to keep for now. These won’t be used for application traffic, but you might need them for specific cluster management purposes.
NOTE: Remember to restart Nginx after making configuration changes.

In the blog post you linked, the author targets control plane nodes. And this is what makes it confusing for me.

You can follow that blog which is helpful to you

Yes, but in this blog he targets the control nodes and not the worker nodes. Do you understand that?

yes you are right but what I suggest you try to follow that blog that helpful to resolve your issue.

@ user3142695 Have you gone through my solution & the answer helps to resolve your issue, if not let me know, I am happy to assist you further.

No, I didn't get it solved - using the blog...
